# Maximal entropy distribution with given conditionals

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, entropy

It is well known that of all the joint distributions $p(x,y)$ with fixed marginals $p(x),p(y)$, the one with the highest entropy is:
$$
p(x,y)=p(x)p(y).
$$

Suppose instead that we have conditionals. Namely:

> Which probability distribution $p(x,y,z)$, with fixed $p(x|y)$ and $p(x|z)$, has maximal entropy?

is there even an explicit formula?

(Note: one is tempted to take $p(x,y,z)$ such that $p(x|y,z)=p(x|y)p(x|z)$, but I think this is misleading, right?)

Feel free to edit question and tags appropriately.

Thanks!

(Crossposted from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160468/maximal-entropy-distribution-with-given-conditionals), where nobody could answer.)

Comment: Do $x$, $y$ and $z$ take their values from finite sets?  Perhaps, you could also comment on why you start with three variables (instead of two), and why only have $p(x|y)$ and $p(x|z)$ as constraints and not, say, $p(x|y,z)$, $p(y|z,x)$ and $p(z|x,y)$ or any other choice.

Comment: A closed form solution for the max ent distribution with given marginals (beyond 1-marginals) is fairly well-unknown. (By "well-unknown" I mean "well-known that it's not known." It might even be known that no such thing exists... From a quick google, see p. 10 [here](http://l2r.cs.uiuc.edu/~danr/Teaching/CS598-05/Lectures/Lec8-maxent.pdf).) Using Lagrange multipliers you can always write it in an exponential form, but the terms appearing in that exponential formula don't have simple closed formulae...

Answer (score 3):

You can find a full formula in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00752v3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a cute problem, but in most cases, you will be able to reach an arbitrarily high entropy.

Basically, for any $p(z)$ such that : $\int p(z)p(x|z)p(x|y) dxdydz $ is finite, you have a joint distribution that respects your condition.

Depending on your p(x|y) function, all p(z) could respect that condition (for example, if $\int p(x|y)dy \leq B$ for all $x$), in which case you can reach an abitrary entropy from p(z) alone

Comment: I suspect the OP assumes $x,y,z$ are chosen from a finite set.