# Maximal entropy distribution on three variables knowing its marginals on any two

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, nonlinear-optimization, entropy

**Observation 0:** Given a finite set $X$, the probability distribution on $X$ with highest entropy is the uniform one.  This is well known.

**Observation 1:** Given two finite sets $X,Y$ and two probability distributions, $p$ on $X$ and $q$ on $Y$, there always exists a probability distribution on $X\times Y$ which has these given distributions as marginals, namely the one $p(x)\,q(y)$ whose projections are independent, and it is the one with highest entropy.  (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239941/maximizing-joint-entropy) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185264/maximum-entropy-distribution-given-second-order-marginals).)

**Question:** Given three finite sets $X,Y,Z$ and three probability distributions, $p$ on $X\times Y$, $q$ on $X\times Z$ and $r$ on $Y\times Z$:

- how can I decide (in function of $p,q,r$) whether there is a probability distribution on $X\times Y\times Z$ which has these given distributions as pairwise marginals? (I mean, is there a simpler way to state this than by writing the obvious linear feasibility problem expressing it?)
- and more importantly, assuming there is one, how can I compute (in function of $p,q,r$) the one with highest entropy?  does this distribution (or this problem) at least have a name?

I am interested both in what can theoretically be said about this problem/distribution, and about computing it in practice.  We can assume $|X|=|Y|=|Z|=2$ if this is of help.

(A similar question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211147/maximal-entropy-distribution-with-given-conditionals), but it's not quite the same setup, and not as symmetric.)

Comment: Just to clarify: with respect to which reference measure are you computing your entropy?

Comment: Also, I presume you enforce the obvious compatibility between the two-marginales $p,q,r$, otherwise there might not even exist a joint distribution on $X\times Y\times Z$ (in your notations one must have for example $\pi^x\# p =\pi^x\#q$ and so on, by permutation)

Comment: One last comment: if one of your three 2-marginals is induced by a map (say for example $p(dx,dy)=\mu(dx)\otimes \delta_{T(x)}(dy)$ for some map $T:X\to Y$) then there exists only one posisble three-distribution, this is given for example in lemma 5.3.2 in the book Gradient flows in metric spaces [..].by L. Ambrosio, N. Gigli, and G. Savaré. So in that case the maximization is not really interesting. But I guess for probabilists the case of transport-induced couplings is not particulartly relevant, is it?

Comment: Note that in the case |X|=|Y|=|Z|=2, constraining the 2-marginals is the same as constraining the moments of degree <=2, so the log of the maximum entropy distribution is a degree-2 polynomial. Solving in practice is then an exercise in root-finding (solving for the coefficients of the polynomial that give the desired marginals/moments).

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Sorry, the entropy is computed wrt the uniform distribution on every finite set involved. And yes, there is a compatibility condition on $p,q,r$: the first part of my question is whether there is a simple way to express it (but I guess this isn't really interesting unless it also helps answer the second part).

Answer (score 1):

This is only about $|X|=|Y|=|Z|=2$ case: let $X=Y=Z=\{0,1\}$. And $f$ be a "seed" joint distribution on $X\times Y\times Z$. Then if another distribution has same pairwise marginals, there difference is one dimensional: $\mu$ on $(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ and $-\mu$ on compliment.

Then maximizing entropy is equivalent to $(f(0,0,0)+\mu)(f(1,1,0)+\mu)(f(1,0,1)+\mu)(f(0,1,1)+\mu)=(f(1,0,0)-\mu)(f(0,1,0)-\mu)(f(0,0,1)-\mu)(f(1,1,1)-\mu)$. Which seems no simple expression of roots are available.

---

Some updates on general case: for every 2-subset of $X,Y$ and $Z$, there is such pertubations and if $f$ is the distribution maximizing entropy, it should satisfy $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)f(x_1,y_1,z_0)f(x_1,y_0,z_1)f(x_0,y_1,z_1)=f(x_1,y_0,z_0)f(x_0,y_1,z_0)f(x_0,y_0,z_1)f(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. Which indicates $f(x,y,z)=\exp(u(x,y)+v(y,z)+w(x,z))$ for some $u,v,w$. It's not hard to show it's also a sufficient condition.